# Prove $q \lor r \vdash (q \land s) \lor (s \to r)$ using natural deduction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

Am I going in the right direction? I'm stuck after this point and I don't really know what to do from here. I know I have to assume and introduce s but I'm unsure how.

1. q v r premise
2. q ʌ s assumption
3. q ʌe 2,3
4. s ʌe 2,4
5. r assumption

Comment: What if s true, r false, p true, q false? Then assumption holds, not conclusion.

Comment: sorry it is a (q v r) on premise

Comment: Joemans Then to make conclusion false requires s true and r false, then also q false, from which (q or r) is false. This only shows (to me) argument seems valid. What is e in your system? [see lines 3,4]

Comment: e is the elimination notation where to get from line 2 to 3 you assume that q and s are true thus q must be true

Comment: @coffeemath  $\land$-e is used in some deductive systems to denote the instantiation of a variable (p) from $p\land q$, or of $q$ from $p\land q$.

Comment: @coffeemath: Or more 'accurately', it refers to $\land$-elimination, because you derive from a given sentence its constituent parts by eliminating the connective. Most natural deductive systems have rules that generally come in pairs, one introduction rule for deriving compound sentences and one elimination rule for using them.

Comment: @user21820 More accurately, it refers to $\land$-elimination, because you start with something that has $\land$ as it's principal connective, and then derive something where *that* $\land$ is not in what you infer (though another $\land$ may exist).  Also, *all* the introduction rules that I have ever seen *allow* for the use of compound sentences.  Note DanielV's proof sketch or mine, and you might just see a suggestion of starting with a compound sentence and then using a disjunction introduction rules.  This suggests that introduction rules got designed *for* using compound sentences.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood: I was not talking to you, and I never said that introduction rules do not allow making compound sentences out of already compound sentences.

Comment: @user21820 I didn't say anything about "making compound sentences".  Nor did you.  Nonetheless, *for the exercise above*, at some point anyone who solves this exercise probably will start with a compound sentence and infer to a distinct compound sentence via an introduction rule.

Comment: @Joemans: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2831/troll-or-skeptic/2867.

Answer (score 2):

Fitch style natural deduction.  Unfortunately the excluded middle assumption on $s$ is not avoidable.

$$\begin{array} {rll}
(1) & q \lor r & \text{Given} \\
\\
(2) & \quad \quad q & \text{Premise} \\
(3) & \quad \quad s \lor \lnot s & \text{Excluded Middle on s} \\
(4) & \quad \quad \quad \quad s & \text{Premise} \\
    & \quad \quad \quad \quad \vdots & \text{Fill these in} \\
(5) & \quad \quad \quad \quad (q \land s) \lor (s \to r) &  \\
\\
(6) & \quad \quad \quad \quad \lnot s & \text{Premise} \\
    & \quad \quad \quad \quad \vdots & \text{Fill these in} \\
(7) & \quad \quad \quad \quad (q \land s) \lor (s \to r) &  \\
\\
(8) & \quad \quad (q \land s) \lor (s \to r) & \text{Or Elimination of 3, 4 to 5, 6 to 7} \\
\\
(9) & \quad \quad r & \text{Premise} \\
    & \quad \quad \vdots & \text{Fill in the dots} \\
(10) & \quad \quad (q \land s) \lor (s \to r) & \\
\\
(11) & (q \land s) \lor (s \to r) & \text{Or Elimination of 1, 2 to 8, 9 to 10} \\
\end{array}$$

That's the basic outline.  Let me know if you need hints filling in the dots.

Comment: I don't believe the approach I outlined would require an excluded middle assumption on s.  But, we'd have to know more about the particular natural deduction system also.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood You assume the excluded middle (more specifically double elimination) on $((q\land s) \lor (s \to r))$, which I tentatively think is an equivalent assumption.

Comment: @DanielV: Yes over intuitionistic logic both double negation elimination and LEM are equivalent rules in the sense that adding either one gives classical logic. However, note that Kleene's 3-valued logic satisfies double negation elimination but not LEM. Just thought you might like to know. =)

Comment: @user21820 No, Kleene's 3-valued logic does not satisfy double negation elimination.  That system does not have a single tautology.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood: You misinterpret me. It **does** satisfy the inference rule "$\neg \neg P \vdash P$". Whether or not you can derive anything at all is irrelevant. Secondly, there **are** ways to extend Kleene's 3-valued logic (such as via some type theory) such that it has tautologies.

Comment: @user21820 Yes, Kleene 3-valued logic satisfies the inference rule $\lnot$$\lnot$P $\vdash$ P.  But, for the very same reason that it satisfies that inference rule, it also satisfies the inference rule P $\vdash$ Q.  Any system that doesn't have any tautologies, satisfies every inference rule with a premiss by default.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood: As I said already, **there are ways to extend Kleene's 3-valued logic to have tautologies** and some of these ways do satisfy double negation elimination but **not** LEM.

Answer (score 1):

So, you start with a disjunction.  Thus, you might manage to use disjunction elimination to solve this.

If you assume r, hopefully, you can see how you can get to ((q$\land$s)$\lor$(s$\rightarrow$r)).

Now suppose that you assume 1. q.

Next assume 2. $\lnot$((q$\land$s)$\lor$(s$\rightarrow$r)).

That hopefully will enable you to produce $\lnot$(q$\land$s).

Once you have that, hopefully you can produce ($\lnot$q$\lor$$\lnot$s).

But, we have q still in effect.  So, hopefully you have some way that you can now produce $\lnot$s.

Hopefully then you can produce (s$\rightarrow$r) which makes getting to ((q$\land$s)$\lor$(s$\rightarrow$r) possible in one step.

Then we discharge 2. and somehow get to ((q$\land$s)$\lor$(s$\rightarrow$r)) with just 1. still under effect.

That hopefully makes using disjunction elimination with the premiss (q$\lor$r) possible.